# woocommerce execute php when user activates membership

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, membership

I found hook:

```
wc_memberships_activated
```

description says:

```
Runs when Memberships is activated.
```

I think that it runs all time as membership is activated.
How can I run script like this:

```
if (user just bought membership){
//execute something
}
```

Script should be executed once as user bought membership

Answer (score 0):

please use this funtion:

```
add_action('wc_memberships_activated','your_function');

your_function(){
  .... here your code
}
```

In this case, please user this function:

```
add_filter( 'wc_memberships_grant_access_from_new_purchase','your_function',20,2);

your_function( $boolVal, $args ) {

 $user_id = $args['user_id'],
 $product_id = $args['product_id'],
 $order_id = $args['order_id'],

 $hasAlreadyMembership = get_user_meta($user_id,'_hasMembership',false);

 if(!$hasAlreadyMembership){
  .... run your code
 }

 update_user_meta($user_id,'_hasMembership',true);

 return $boolVal
}
```

With add_action you add your own function to hook.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know how to use hooks. Question was: How to run php function when user has JUST bought membership. Execute only ONCE at the moment af activating membership

Comment: please see editet answer